# What (good) Java RADIUS server libraries are out there?

Tags: java, hammer

I've only been able to find two thus far, namely [TinyRadius](http://tinyradius.sourceforge.net/), which itself discourages production use and [AXL](http://www.axlradius.com/), which is pay-only.

[JRadius](http://coova.org/wiki/index.php/JRadius) seems tied to [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/), which isn't a library and will need a lot of cajoling to function like one.

Comment: checkout FreeRADIUS.net  ,radius server implementation for windows and its free.

Answer (score 4):

List from http://freeradius.org/related/opensource.html (not copying the descriptions because the page says it's copyright *rolleyes*):

Cistron - http://www.radius.cistron.nl/

GNU Radius - http://www.gnu.org/software/radius/

FreeRADIUS - http://freeradius.org/

JRadius - http://www.coova.org/JRadius

ICRADIUS - http://www.icradius.org/

OpenRADIUS - http://www.openradius.net/

XtRADIUS - http://xtradius.sourceforge.net/

YARD RADIUS - http://sourceforge.net/projects/yardradius

Answer (score 3):

OK, it seems a pure JAVA open-source RADIUS server simply does not exist.

For completeness, I think I'm going to try one of the Python implementations through Jython to get it running in Java and start replacing pieces as and when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Directory project (http://directory.apache.org) is looking into this as people are intending to donate some java code. If and when this is successfully concluded, we (the Directory community) will most probably start a sub project and build a community to further this code into a full-fledged java based Open Source Radius server.

Comment: I am also looking for a Java implementation of the RADIUS server. Any news from your open source radius server?